# "Error: The given sign-in provider is disabled for Firebase project." but i've enabled firebase google auth

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

[image: Error]

[image: Firebase Console]

I'm using ionic 3 for android app but got error in google plus login with firebase. Integrated ionic and cordova g+ plugins and my code is

```
gPlusLogin(){
    this.nativeGLogin();
}

async nativeGLogin(){
    try {
       const gplusUser = await this.googlePlus.login({
         'webClientId': '235*********ie.apps.googleusercontent.com',
         'offline': true
       })

       return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken))
     } catch (error) {
         this.errorAlert(error)
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `GithubAuthProvider` with your `signInWithCredential` when you meant to use Google sign in, that's probably the problem.